# SCP won't find file even though it exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, scp

I'm trying to SCP some files from a remote server. The command I'm using is:

`scp -r -i ~/path/to/key ubuntu@address:/home/ubuntu/analysis .`

I receive an error:

`scp: /home/ubuntu/analysis: No such file or directory`.

If I scp another file in my home directory, it does work, e.g.

`scp -r -i ~/path/to/key ubuntu@address:/home/ubuntu/.viminfo .`

If I create a new file, e.g. with `touch new_file.txt`, I also cannot download that file.

The permissions and owners for `.viminfo` and the directory `analysis` are standard.

[image]

Why isn't the SCP working? I have been able to download files from this server before, but something has changed.

Quite confusing - any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: That's weird. I would suggest pulling out the logs.

Comment: is `analysis` a directory?

Comment: does user `ubuntu` owns/has permission on the files you're trying to copy?

Comment: Yes I think so. Thanks for your help - I actually ended up remaking the whole AWS instance in the end because I think I got the whole thing into a weird state by messing with ownerships/users. Still have no idea what was wrong but was able to avoid the problem by starting again. Thanks anyway!